# Installing Kafka 2.7.0 and getting this Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install Kafka 2.7.0 in windows 10. I have been following a linked in course and downloaded a tar file from https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/kafka/2.7.0/kafka-2.7.0-src.tgz
After extracting it, I tried running the following commands which gave me the error mentioned in the
title.

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
```

I don't get any zookeeper tar file from the downloaded Kafka tar file. Any help is appreciated.
The issue is dated 30th Jan 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've downloaded Kafka source code, not the Kafka binaries, so there's no built classes there to run

You also should use the shell scripts in WSL2 rather than the batch files in CMD

https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/